# Un-parenthesized tuple gives a "syntax error" in an "if" statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

Unparenthesized tuples:

This snippet is fine:

```
for i in 1,2, :
...     print(f'i={i}')
```

But this gives a "syntax error":

```
>>> i = 5
>>> if i in 1,2, :
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    if i in 1,2,:
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

and the same without the trailing comma.

Parenthesizing the tuple works fine:

```
if i in (1,2) :
```

Note this:

```
>>> if (i in 5,6) :
...     print(f'{i}')
...
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

So the issue is *not* the "if" statement, but the conditional expression.

Comment: Very similar question here : [when-are-parentheses-required-around-a-tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16017811/12128167)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comma Syntax: rationale behind a hanging comma in a statement being a SyntaxError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30221984/comma-syntax-rationale-behind-a-hanging-comma-in-a-statement-being-a-syntaxerro)

Comment: What *is* your question? Unparenthesised tuples give syntax errors at a lot of places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the answer in the [full grammar specification](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/grammar.html) (Python 3.6). Specifically, these definitions answer your question:

```
testlist: test (',' test)* [',']

for_stmt: 'for' exprlist 'in' testlist ':' suite ['else' ':' suite]
if_stmt: 'if' test ':' suite ('elif' test ':' suite)* ['else' ':' suite]
```

Basically, in your first piece of code `i` is part of `exprlist` and `1,2` is your `testlist` (a list of one or more tests, separated by a comma). In particular, you could write tests in place of those numbers. `testlist` could be something like `1,2,True==False,3 if False else 5`.

In your second piece of code, `i in 1` is a test. It is then followed by a comma, and that's why you're getting an exception. The Python grammar specification does not allow you to have two tests in that statement. Instead, `i in (1,2)` is parsed as a single test, therefor it works.

Answer (score 1):

the for statement is a iterator statement and hence it works fine and where as the if statement is a conditional statement which expects a single value/entity or an expresion that returns a single value/entity and in your case you are providing 2 values/entities which it cannot compare to make decisions and hence you need to use "()" to have it as an single entity.